# Can One Campaign Influence an Opportunity More Than Once?

Tags: campaign-influence

We are using customizable campaign influence.

For now I have two models, First Touch and Last Touch. I'm deriving these from the Responded date of a Campaign Member relative to the Account, so it is possible that the First Touch and Last Touch came from the same Campaign. In other words, if two employees of the same company respond - say, Sally responds to the Campaign on Jan. 1, she could be First Touch, but if Joe responds on Feb 1, he could be the Last Touch.

However when I try to insert the records I get the following error:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, A Campaign Influence Record for this Opportunity with same Contact and Campaign already exists.

The record I am trying to insert contains the Opportunity ID, the Campaign ID, the Model ID (Last Touch or First Touch). There is no Contact ID, so when the error says it can't have a Contact *and* Campaign, that doesn't seem to jive.

Here is a dump of the object I extracted from a debug statement, just before it is inserted:

> {CampaignId=701c0000000XjNGAA0, Influence=50, ModelId=03Vc00000008OKfEAM, OpportunityId=006c000000H6Y71AAF}

The way my business logic works, we will have a 2nd, equivalent record as well:

> {CampaignId=701c0000000XjNGAA0, Influence=50, ModelId=03Vc00000008OKfEAM, OpportunityId=006c000000H6Y71AAF}

Am I breaking a fundamental rule here, or is there something I'm missing? TIA.